# pivot application windows phone 8.1 navigation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I am developing a windows phone application for my firm.

I've just manually created  pivot items in a basic page. The application is working fine except the back button navigation. When I click on any button inside a pivot item it is navigating to desired page but when i click back button it is always navigating to pivot item 1 instead of the one from which the click event is originated.

My XAML looks like this

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentRoot"><Pivot x:Name="Test" Title="test book" FontSize="{ThemeResource TextStyleExtraLargeFontSize}">
        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <PivotItem x:Name="pitem1" Header="item1">
     <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                      
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button x:Name="bt1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" Click="bt1_Click"/>               
                <Button x:Name="bt2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Click="bt2_Click"/>             
                <Button x:Name="bt3" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Click="bt3_Click"/>          
                <Rectangle StrokeThickness="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="11" Stroke="#FF015C1F">            
                </Rectangle>
            </Grid>
        </PivotItem>
        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <PivotItem x:Name="pitem2" Header="item2" >             
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button x:Name="bt4" Grid.Row="1" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Click="bt4_Click"/ >
                <Button x:Name="bt5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Click="bt5_click" />
                </Grid>            
        </PivotItem>
        <!--Pivot item two-->
        <PivotItem x:Name="pitem3" Header="item3">             
            <Grid >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button x:Name="bt6" Grid.Row="1"  Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Click="bt6_Click"/>             
               <Button x:Name="bt7" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Click="bt7_Click"/>              
                <Button x:Name="bt8" Grid.Row="2"  Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Click="bt8_Click" />
              </Grid>
        </PivotItem>
```

For example : If I click "bt7" present inside the pivot item 3, it navigates to page and when i click back button it is navigating to pivot item 1 instead of item 3.

Am I missing something or the problem is i have created pivot item manually?

I'm new to C# and XAML. Any help would be highly appreciated.

UPDATE :

```
    public home()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();         
       this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
        this.navigationHelper.LoadState += this.NavigationHelper_LoadState;
        this.navigationHelper.SaveState += this.NavigationHelper_SaveState;
    }
    public NavigationHelper NavigationHelper
    {
        get { return this.navigationHelper; }
    }
    public ObservableDictionary DefaultViewModel
    {
        get { return this.defaultViewModel; }
    }
    private void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {
    }
   private void NavigationHelper_SaveState(object sender, SaveStateEventArgs e)
    {
    }
    #region NavigationHelper registration
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {   
        this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom(e);         
    }
    #endregion
           private async void bt1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            home obj = new home();
            var result = await obj.GetToken4(sid); 
          if (result.Substring(0, 2) == "No")
            {                    
                MessageDialog msgbox = new MessageDialog("No records found", "e-Book!");
                await msgbox.ShowAsync();                 
            }
            else
            {                  
                this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(firstpage), result);
            }
        }     
    }
    private async Task<string> GetToken4(string sid)
    {
        string postData = "id=" + sid;
        var res = await post4("parameter", postData);
        return res;
    }
    private async Task<string> post4(string url, string postdata)
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("myurl")) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata);
        //request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        using (var requestStream = await Task<Stream>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetRequestStream, request.EndGetRequestStream, request))
        {
            await requestStream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        WebResponse responseObject = await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, request);
        var responseStream = responseObject.GetResponseStream();
        var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        string received = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
        return received;
    }
    private async void bt2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       home obj = new home();
            var result = await obj.GetToken4(sid); 
          if (result.Substring(0, 2) == "No")
            {                    
                MessageDialog msgbox = new MessageDialog("No records found", "e-Book!");
                await msgbox.ShowAsync();                 
            }
            else
            {                  
                this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(secondpage), result);
            }
        }          
    }
    private async Task<string> GetToken5(string sid)
    {
        string postData = "dep=" + sid;
        var res = await post5("parameter1", postData);
        return res;
    }
    private async Task<string> post5(string url, string postdata)
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("myurl")) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata);
        //request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        using (var requestStream = await Task<Stream>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetRequestStream, request.EndGetRequestStream, request))
        {
            await requestStream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        WebResponse responseObject = await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, request);
        var responseStream = responseObject.GetResponseStream();
        var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        string received = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
        return received;
    }

} }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your page is completely reloaded when navigating back and therefor all controls will be in their default state (e.g. pivot is on the first item).

You can either save/restore the state in the OnNavigatedTo and OnNavigatedFrom methods, or activate page caching by setting your page's NavigationCacheMode to Enabled or Required in the constructor.

Comment: I have tried NavigationCacheMode to Enabled or Required in my xaml. but when I click back button the pivot item page is completely blank.    this is what i have done          `<Page
    x:Class="kvbebook.home"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:kvbebook"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    RequestedTheme="Light"
    NavigationCacheMode="Enabled">`

Comment: I don't think it works in Xaml. Set it in Codebehind, in the constructor. One of those rare quirks...

Comment: Also, if you use Enabled, check for the cache size (by default it is set somewhere in app.xaml.cs).

Comment: I have tried using the  `this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;` in the page constructor, but still I'm getting blank page while navigating back to pivot item page.

Comment: Please update the code in your question, otherwise this will be hard to follow. Just for clarification: You set the NavigationCacheMode on the page you want to have preserved in memory. If the page you are navigating to afterwards does not show anything, then it is a different problem that has to do with your loading code.

Comment: The *home* class is your page, right? Why are you creating extra instances of it in your click handlers? And that's just the navigation part. If that works, (e.g. The second page is displayed), it means it works. You should check what happens when loading your second page.